# How to scan I2C slave address on STM32?

Tags: arduino, stm32, i2c, cortex-m

I'm trying to communicate with an mpu9250 with STM32 via I2C, but I can't determine the slave address. (I am using a usb bootloader.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the datasheet
(https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf)
page 12,

the default I²C slave address of the MPU9250 is `0b1101000`(=`0x68`=`104`) or `0b1101001`(=`0x69`=`105`) depending on the value of pin `AD0`.

If you use two MPU9250, you can differentiate them by using one with the first address and the other one with the other address by putting a logic `LOW` on the `AD0` pin of the first MPU and a logic `HIGH` on the `AD0` pin of the second MPU.